# Simple state managment with contextAPI in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-context

I want to set up a simple global state so that the site owner can update some numeric values whenever he wants to. I created a Provider, added it into custom _app.js and into his admin.js where he can change the value via input and into aboutme.js in which the value should get displayed at the end.

Here is my StateProvider.js:

```
import React, { useContext, createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const AppContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [dvds, setDvds] = useState(Number);

  let sharedState = {
    dvds,
    setDvds,
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={sharedState}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}
```

which I imported into _app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.scss';
import { StateProvider } from '../lib/appCtx';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

    return (
      <>
        <StateProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </StateProvider>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Here is the admin.js to set the value:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/Admin.module.scss';
import { AppContext } from '../lib/appCtx';

export default function Admin() {

  const { dvds, setDvds } = useContext(AppContext);
  const updateState = () => createContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <>
        ...    
            <div className={styles.card}>
              <div className={styles.title}>Number of DVDs</div>
              <p className={styles.text}>
                {new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
                  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 0,
                }).format(dvds)}
              </p>
              <input
                type='text'
                onChange={(e) => setDvds(e.target.value)}
                onKeyPress={updateState}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        ...
    </>
  );
}
```

and last but not least the aboutme.js to display the value from context:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from '../styles/Aboutme.module.scss';
import { AppContext, useAppContext } from '../lib/appCtx';

export default function AboutMe() {


  function thousands_separators(num) {
    var num_parts = num.toString().split('.');
    num_parts[0] = num_parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
    return num_parts.join('.');
  }

  const dvds = AppContext.dvs;

  return (
    <div>
        ...
            <div className={styles.col}>
              <p>
                <span>
                  {new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
                    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
                    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
                  }).format(useAppContext(dvds))}
                </span>
                <br /> dvds in collection
              </p>           
            </div>
          </div>
     ...
  );
}
```

So I want to pass the typed number from admin.js over the Provider into the aboutme.js.
Would anyone be so nice to explain me why it doesn`t work and helping me by providing the right source? Thank you guys!!

Comment: In the `aboutme.js`, if you want to retrieve the `dvds` context value you need to get it with `const { dvds } = useAppContext();`. Then `dvds` will have the value set in `admin.js`.

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you for taking time to answer - if I click on updateBtn I get the following error message in my console: **Anonymous arrow functions cause Fast Refresh to not preserve local component state.** Is my updateState handler function wrong?

Comment: What is your `updateState` function trying to achieve? It does seem to be wrong.

Comment: @juliomalves The goal was to hand over the value into context.

Comment: Call `setDvds` like you do on the `onClick` event.